# MBBuild fail if string exists in any file in the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild, octopus-deploy

Is there a way to have MSBuild fail if any of the files included in a solution have a certain string in them?

In this specific case, we are using DbUp with Ocotpus Deploy to deploy SQL scripts in the form of .sql files.  With our deployment process we specifically target each database directly.  Occasionally, scripts will get created that have in them `USE [devDatabase]`.  I'd like to fail the build if this string exists in any of the .sql files that are part of the build.

Is that possible?

Comment: you mean something like a post-build step which reads all lines of all .sql files and raises an error when the string 'USE [devDatabase]' is found?

Comment: @stijn, yes, that would do the trick.  Just unsure what that looks like!

Comment: Although it might need to be a pre-build step since DbUp requires the files the embedded resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an MsBuild solution, add this to the project file:

```
<Target Name="CheckSqlFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <SqlFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildThisFile)" Targets="ErrorIfDevDataBaseUsed" Properties="SqlFileToCheck=%(SqlFiles.Identity)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="ErrorIfDevDataBaseUsed">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(SqlFileToCheck)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Sql" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <Error Text="Found devDatabase in $(SqlFileToCheck)"
         Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(Sql.Identity)').Contains('USE [devDatabase]'))" />
</Target>
```

It will run before the *Build* target. There are many other targets so if this one is too late or too early, run msbuild with the /v:d flag and figure out before (or after, using `AfterTargets=...`) which target you want it to run. If it's slow, or you prefer PowerShell, you can off course apply the same principle and invoke Powershell instead in the CheckSqlFiles target using e.g. `<Exec command="PowerShell checksql.ps1 $(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)"/>` where checksql.ps1 is like AlexM's answer but taling the directory to run in as an argument.

Comment: This worked great.  For our project with a little over 100 .sql files, it added about 6 seconds to the build time, well worth it.

Comment: A significant amount of time might also be spent just in listing the directoris recursively (the **\*.sql part) so if you know the exact location of the sql file you can gain time by being more specific there

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to have an additional Octopus step to make this check and fail a deployment if there are files alike.

Would just be a PowerShell script step :

```
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Projects\SQL -Filter *.sql -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "use " | group path | select name)
if ($Files.length -eq 0) {
  write-host "no SQL files with 'USE'" 
} else {
  foreach ($file in $Files) { 
    write-host $file.Name
  }
    Exit 1

}
```

Given your next step has Conditions as below it should fail:
[image]

Comment: I like the idea, but DbUp requires that the files be included as embedded resources so I don't believe Octopus could see them by the time the artifact get to deployment.

Comment: Haven't used DbUp, so didn't know it requires embedded resources. I generate dacpacs instead and then create diff script and apply at the time of deployment. When are the files generated/embedded? You could extract embedded resources from a dll, but potentially there should be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a unit test that reads all the embedded SQL files and checks for that statement.

Also have a look at https://github.com/andrewabest/Conventional, it may be a base for starting similar tests.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible to do this check with an Octopus step, as @AlexM demonstrates, but it seems like Octopus is not the best place for this kind of checks.

I mean, is there any situation where you would like to deploy the script as is?

If the answer is no, then this check belongs in your build server (TeamCity, Jenkins, etc.) and **the build should fail** if a script contains the string you're looking for, **and you shouldn't send the artifacts to Octopus at all** - which means it can't be deployed anyway.

Lots of ways to do that on the build server... With Powershell, MSBuild (as @stijn points out), etc.